# What will break when I replace all ExpressionStatements during custom compilation?

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl

For a DSL I am working on, I am considering transforming all top level `ExpressionStatement`s into a `MethodCallExpression`. For instance, I want the DSL user to be able to just type something in quote marks and the DSL will do some basic, common thing with it within the domain.

I wrote a little test (below), which transforms `ExpressionStatement`s to `println` `MethodCallExpression`s, and the result appears pleasing - it is not printing out any Strings I wouldn't expect printed, and not interfering with returning Strings from methods, closures, etc.

But what else might I have broken that I am not testing for?

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.CompilationCustomizer 
import org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.GeneratorContext
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression                          
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression                          
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression                          
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement 

class myTransform extends CompilationCustomizer {

    public myTransform(CompilePhase p) { super(p) }

    public void call (SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) {

        def statements = source.getAST().classes[0].methods[1].code.statements

        statements.eachWithIndex { stmt, n ->
            try {
                if (stmt in ExpressionStatement && stmt.expression.type.typeClass in [String, GString]) {
                    statements[n] = new ExpressionStatement(
                        new MethodCallExpression(
                            new VariableExpression("this"),
                            "println",
                            new ArgumentListExpression([stmt.expression])
                        )
                    )
                }
            } catch (Error e) { }
        } 

    }
}   


new GroovyShell(
    getClass().classLoader, 
    new CompilerConfiguration().addCompilationCustomizers( new myTransform(CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS))
).evaluate '''
    "Print me 1"
    "${"And " + "me 2"}"
    "${3}"
    "nope" + "not this time"
    class Foo { static String getFooString(String s) { "Foo" } }
    Foo.getFooString("no")
    public String getBar() { "Bar" }
    getBar()
    "getBar" ()
    println "Print me only once 4"
    def a = "nope"
    a
    def c = { String s -> "blah" ; s.toUpperCase() }
    c ( "out" )
    try { "nil" } catch (any) { "nil" } finally { "nil" }
    switch ("nada") { case "nada": "nada" }
    123
    new Foo() // TODO: throws an Error in the Transform, how to avoid it other than catching and ignoring it?
    return "Return me, don't print me."
'''
```

GroovyConsole Output:

```
Print me 1
And me 2
3
Print me only once 4
Result: Return me, don't print me.
```